# How to do Direct Input Gamepad in Python

Tags: python, controller, gamepad, directinput

So I want to do a **direct input** from **gamepad** in **python**. All I have found from the internet is with **PYXinput**, but it seems when I try **check** it with **x360ce** and **vjoy**, it doesn't do anything. Do anyone know how to do the direct input with a gamepad? or how to use this PYXinput? Any clue would be appreciated!

This is the source code that i used from PYXinput : https://github.com/bayangan1991/PYXInput